# How to get list of supported standards in Clang?

Tags: clang

I found this in MAN:

```
   -std=language
       Specify the language standard to compile for.

   -ansi
       Same as -std=c89.
```

But where to find the list of all supported standards by my installed compiler?

```
clang -std=??? test.c
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Check this file:** llvm.git/tools/clang/include/clang/Frontend/LangStandards.def
[online version from github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/include/clang/Basic/LangStandards.def)
The standard supported by compiler is keep changing, you could check this file and try it yourself.

```
// C++ modes
LANGSTANDARD(cxx98, "c++98",
             "ISO C++ 1998 with amendments",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | Digraphs)
LANGSTANDARD(cxx03, "c++03",
             "ISO C++ 1998 with amendments",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | Digraphs)
LANGSTANDARD(gnucxx98, "gnu++98",
             "ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU extensions",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | Digraphs | GNUMode)

LANGSTANDARD(cxx0x, "c++0x",
             "ISO C++ 2011 with amendments",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | CPlusPlus11 | Digraphs)
LANGSTANDARD(cxx11, "c++11",
             "ISO C++ 2011 with amendments",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | CPlusPlus11 | Digraphs)
LANGSTANDARD(gnucxx0x, "gnu++0x",
             "ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | CPlusPlus11 | Digraphs | GNUMode)
LANGSTANDARD(gnucxx11, "gnu++11",
             "ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions",
             LineComment | CPlusPlus | CPlusPlus11 | Digraphs | GNUMode)
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @Åsmund fixed. It was just the transition from `master` to `main`.

Answer (score 16):

Just specify any BS standard and clang will print those acceptable like so:

```
c:\LLVM\bin>clang++.exe -std=blabla main.cpp
error: invalid value 'blabla' in '-std=blabla'
note: use 'c++98' or 'c++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++98' or 'gnu++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020' standard
note: use 'gnu++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions' standard
```

;-)

Comment: `touch dummy.cpp; clang -std=dummy dummy.cpp`  for the lazy ones

Comment: Prints the error but not the notes of suggestions on Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2).

Comment: Same for clang++ 3.4.2 on Centos 7: Prints error but not suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/6b15b6d3c1f8274162d5881b05d79aeddd5d6aad

> In case user did not provide valid standard name for -std option,
>   available values (with short description) will be reported.